# Consume WCF with parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wcf-rest

I cant consume WCF with parameters in URL

My method in WCF:
`Login(user,pass)`

My aspx.cs code:

`Service1Client respLogin = new Service1Client().Login(user, pass);`

My web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="AllocationBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <client>
            <endpoint name="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                      address="http://1.234.567:8/service1.svc"
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      behaviorConfiguration="AllocationBehavior"
                      contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" />
        </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Error Message: `There was no endpoint listening at that could accept http://1.234.567:8/service1.svc/Login message`

This is correct, `http://1.234.567:8/service1.svc/Login` does not exist (I need to add parameters in URL), but `http://1.234.567:8/service1.svc/Login/user/pass` does exist and response ok!!

I can't add parameters user and pass in URL ...

How I add parameters user & pass in URL using WCF and C#?

Thanks friends!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've forgotten to decorate your service implementation with the [WebGet attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That's how URL parameters are specified in WCF RESTful services.